# en CSS el + es como un before?

Tags: css, input, radiobutton

Estaba buscando un radio input pero en vez de tener el circulo para marcar cual esta seleccionada, que simplemente haya texto y cambie como si fuera un boton, encontre este codigo sencillo pero no entiendo bien, porque si que he dado las pseudo clases :hover :before...etc pero no entiendo esta linea del css si alguien puede explicarme

que hace la linea del `:checked+label` no entiendo, es como un after?

```css
.boxed input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.boxed input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border: solid 2px green;
  background-color: rgb(0, 124, 255);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="boxed">
  <legend>Selecciona un dron de mantenimiento:</legend>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
    <label for="huey">Huey</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
    <label for="louie">Louie</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Selecciona las etiquetas label que esten detras (solo la primera) de un input de tipo radio en estado chequed (seleccionado) que a su vez sea hijo de algun elemento con la clase boxed. Resumiendo, cuando se seleccione ese radio su etiqueta tendra un color de fondo y un borde

Comment: ```input[type="radio"]:checked + label``` es decir, estas cambiando los estilos a tu label en caso de cuando esta seleccionado (checked). El atributo **+**, selecciona el primer elemento <label> que se coloca inmediatamente después de los elementos en este caso ```input[type="radio"]:checked```

Answer (score 1):

El simbolo '+' es conocido como el [hermano adjunto](https://dazzet.co/simbolos-css-hojas-estilo/), y te ayuda a seleccionar cuando hay un elemento junto de otro, en el caso del codigo que hallaste te aplica el estilo solamente si hay un label junto a un radio button seleccionado. He agregado la estructura de HTML para que tu codigo funcione en la pregunta, pero como veras no se parece mucho a un boton.

Puedes cambiar la apariencia del radio input usando la propiedad appearance poniendolo en none y personalizar mediante el pseudo-elemento ::before.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"]::before {
  content: attr(value);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked::before {
  content: attr(value);
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Selecciona un dron de mantenimiento:</legend>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Esto producirá un radio input que se vea como un botón con el texto, el radio input tendrá como contenido el valor del atributo `value`. Cuando esté seleccionado, el botón cambiará de color y el texto se volverá blanco.

Pero como observas el texto no es muy personalizable de esta manera ya que no puede tener espacios ni caracteres personalizados, por eso es comun usar una etiqueta asociada a tu input.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Selecciona un dron de mantenimiento:</legend>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
    <label for="huey">Que viva yo</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Mi apá</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
    <label for="louie">Y la chona</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

En este caso al usar el `+` no estamos seleccionando el radio, sino la etiqueta y le aplicamos los estilos a la etiqueta dependiendo de si esta junto a un radio seleccionado o no. En este caso no es necesario modificar el texto haciendo referencia a content.